# Загрузка картинки через форму в Django

Tags: python, django, формы

Хочу сделать форму через которую можно будет загружать изображения на сайт, но застрял на одном месте и не знаю что делать дальше. Я ток изучаю  Django и ничего еще не знаю.
Я сделал форму по примеру из документации, форма отображается все хорошо, но после того как выбрал картинку и нажал на отправить, ничего не происходит, и в папке media куда я указал чтобы сохранялись файлы, их там нет.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно делать дальше. Сам искал в инете, но так и не нашел ничего :(

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', upload_file),
]
```

## Forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadFile
        fields = ('title', 'image')
```

## views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'form': form})
```

## models.py

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
```

## index.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

По поводу того, что файлы не сохраняются я разобрался, но теперь вылезла другая проблема. Когда добавляю изображение через форму у меня почему то оно само себя копирует, но с другим названием. Что это за бесовщина

Comment: Покажите ещё код шаблона относящийся к форме.

Comment: <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего ваша форма не проходит проверку валидности.

попробуйте добавить отладочный принт в views.py Пример привожу ниже:

**views.py**

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    print(form.is_valid())

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Команда **print(form.is_valid())** в данном коде покажет **в терминале** с каким **результатом** завершается проверка формы.